# Moving data from specific table cells to form fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on the situation to, within Bootstrap with jQuery, move data from one of multiple tables into various form fields. I have different groups with the same tables and depending on which button is pressed, different data should be moved.

The following piece of code shows the issue:
https://www.codeply.com/p/GgpazLylXB

When "Button 1" is pressed, the form field "Name" should be filled with "Eric" while when "Button 2" is pressed, it "Monica" should appear. Similarly, the correct gender should be selected and the birthdate should be filled it.

Tried to write a script myself, but my knowledge is too limited to make it work. I thought openly asking the question would create provide the best creative solutions.

Comment: Please [edit] a [mre] directly into your question. We're not going to go off-site just to understand what you are asking. Please read [ask].